# Rxjs prevent subscribe in subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6, subscribe

I have an array of objects. I need to get array if ids, then call 2 APIs, then close the modal window.

My code is:

```
from(this.alerts)
      .pipe(map(alert => alert._id))
      .subscribe(alertIds => zip(
          this.alertApi.someCall1(alertIds, ...),
          this.alertApi.someCall2(alertIds, ...),
        ).subscribe(() => {
          this.activeModal.close();
        }),
      );
```

Do you have any idea with preventing `subscribe` inside `subscribe`?

Comment: Is `this.alerts` an array of objects with an `_id` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `switchMap` rxjs operator to avoid nested subscriptions.

```js
from(this.alerts)
      .pipe(
         map(alert => alert._id),
         switchMap(alertIds => zip(
           this.alertApi.someCall1(alertIds, ...),
           this.alertApi.someCall2(alertIds, ...)
         ))
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
          this.activeModal.close();
      );
```

More information on switchMap operator can be found [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/).

Comment: Please note this solution will also call `close()` when the observable returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forkJoin`, which is similar to `Promise.all`, and `switchMap`.

[See also: the RxJS docs, specifically example 6, which is similar to your situation.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

```
from(this.alerts)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(alert =>
            forkJoin(
                this.alertApi.someCall1(alert._id),
                this.alertApi.someCall2(alert._id)
            )
        )
    )
).subscribe(() => {
   this.activeModal.close(); 
});
```

Please note the resulting observable will only emit if all inner observables complete.